# perl, no child process w/ "open"

Tags: perl, process, fork, pid, sigchld

Hi I have this problem where the perl script spits back "No child process found at" ...

My script calls several different types of forks, so I tried implementing the perldoc's waitpid() implementation method to be able to use handle both fork & exec & system & qw.

```
 $SIG{CHLD} = sub {
    # don't change $! and $? outside handler
    local ($!, $?);
    my $pid = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG) > 0;
    return if $pid == -1;
    return unless defined $children{$pid};
    delete $children{$pid};
};

    my $pid = fork();
    die "cannot fork" unless defined $pid;
    if ($pid == 0) {
        # ...
        exit 0;
    } else {
        $children{$pid}=1;
        # ...
        exec($command);
   }
```

There is no problem with this part of the execution of the code, however the "No child processor found" occurs when I try to close the filehandle's CLOSE. Can someone explain to me how come this is happening, as I really want to understand this problem more in depth. Do I end up reaping the child process forked by the OPEN call, so that the close doesn't know how to handle the file handle? or maybe I'm 100% off. Any solutions would be appreciated

```
open(RESULTS, "-|", "find $dir\/ -maxdepth 1 -name RESULTS -print0 | xargs -0 cat ") or die $!;
while(<RESULTS>){
if($_ =~ /match/){
    print $_;
 }
  }
 close RESULTS;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`close` on a handle* opened thusly calls `waitpid` to reap the child created by `open`. However, your signal handler managed to reap the child before `close` did, so `close` could not find the child, so `close` returned an error.

You could fix this by changing your signal handler to only reap the children you've created using `fork` (below), or you could ignore that error from `close`.

```
$SIG{CHLD} = sub {
   local ($!, $?, $^E);
   for my $pid (keys(%children)) {
      if (waitpid($pid, WNOHANG) > 0) {
         delete $children{$pid};
      }
   }
};
```

---

* — The proper term is "file *handle*". It is named such  since it allows you to hold onto a file. It's not *handler* as it performs no action.

Comment: What should I do to the modify the signal handler to reap only the signals done by fork? Do you mean something like this?, placing: 
return if ( grep{!$children{$_}}$pid);
 before my $pid = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG) > 0;

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer. Last question What is the purpose of the making the $^E local as well?